# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, sql, exception, sqlexception

```
public class Brothers extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * declaring connection and SQL statement
     */

    Connection cn;
    Statement st;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    Object fname, mname, lname, bdate, nation, statusq,InstNo,  photo, combo, place, mimi; 
    int status;



    public Brothers() {        
        dbconnect _db = new dbconnect();

/*//////////////the above is just to show that I have two prepared statement each for each sql statement that i have //////////*/
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(_db.getHost(), _db.getUsername(), _db.getPassword());
            st=cn.createStatement(); 

 try{

        String Sql="INSERT INTO brothers(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Nationality, InstituteNumber, Status, Picture) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  
        pstmt=cn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        //pstmt.setString(1,txtTrial.getText());('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')
        pstmt.setString(2,txtFirtsName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(3,txtMiddleName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(4,txtLastName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(5,((JTextField)chooserBirthDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pstmt.setString(6,txtPlacBirth.getText());

        String nations=combonation.getSelectedItem().toString();
        pstmt.setString(7,nations);
        pstmt.setString(8,txtInstituteNo.getText());


        pstmt.setObject(9,combostatus.getSelectedItem());
        pstmt.setBytes(10, person_image);

      pstmt.executeUpdate(Sql);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saving Successfull");

        }

        catch(Exception e){

          //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
          e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

When I try to inset data using the above code it throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (10 > number of parameters, which is 9).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
```

I have tried to look over it but I cant find the problem please help!!

Comment: when I use this instead I am able to insert data except for the picture:  

        
        try{
String addrecords="insert into brothers(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Nationality, InstituteNumber, Status, Picture) values('"+
        fname +"', '" +
        mname +"', '" +
        lname +"', '" +
        dave +"', '" +
        place +"', '" +
        isa +"', '" +
        InstNo +"', '" +
        statusq +"', '" +
        photo +"')"; 
        
        //wrapField();
        
        st.executeUpdate(addrecords);
        }

Comment: You should change the title of the question to match the actual message of the exception that you put in the body of the question !

Answer (score 7):

You are starting the insert at position 2 instead 1

```
 pstmt.setString(2,txtFirtsName.getText());
```

Change it to

```
pstmt.setString(1,txtFirtsName.getText());
```

Do the same for the others where the last one will be

```
pstmt.setBytes(9, person_image);
```

Comment: Of course you are right, but either there is another problem, or the error message "Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 0)" is quite misleading. As far as I know you don't have to set the parameters in order (you could set 2, then 3, then 1) so it should crash when he attempts to set 10, not 2 ?

Comment: Please read the exception again, it is "(10 > number of parameters, which is 9)" which means that he is trying to insert a parameter in position 10 but it only support 9 parameters. Also I didn't say that he need to set the parameters in order.

Comment: My table has ten columns: BrothersID,FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Nationality, InstituteNumber, Status, Picture.  BrothersID is an auto increment meaning I don't have to enter anything on it!!! But I even tried by cheating it by creating a text filed that I dont use ...see //pstmt.setString(1,txtTrial.getText()); but still it didnt work

Comment: Sure, sorry, I didn't properly read the exception in the body of thequestion, and look at the title of the question !

Comment: Guys when I do as you have suggested the error changes to: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: @PierreHenry I hadnt seen the title, sorry :)

Comment: @Isaiah could you please update this post with the latest code and the full stack trace? or maybe create a new post since this is a different error... you could solve this one based in our instructions

Answer (score 3):

The number of question marks `?` must equal to the parameter.

If you have 7 parameter then there should be 7 question marks in your statement i.e `insert into table name values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Answer (score 2):

You only have 9 parameters in your SQL statement.

```
String Sql="INSERT INTO brothers(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Nationality, InstituteNumber, Status, Picture) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

When you commented out the first `setString` method call, you should have renumbered the parameter indices for the following calls.  They should be numbered 1 - 9, not 2 - 10.

Comment: Guys when I do as you have suggested the error changes to:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: My table has ten columns: BrothersID,FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Nationality, InstituteNumber, Status, Picture. BrothersID is an auto increment meaning I don't have to enter anything on it!!! But I even tried by cheating it by creating a text filed that I dont use ...see //pstmt.setString(1,txtTrial.getText()); but still it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The index of the first parameter should be 1 not 2, the index of the last parameter should be 9 not 10. When assigning N parameters, the index goes from 1 to N.

Comment: When I do as you have suggested the error changes to: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

use
psmt.executeUpdate();
instead of
pstmt.executeUpdate(Sql);