# uploading a picture using java to Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc

```
  Connection cn;
    Statement st;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    Object fname, mname, lname, bdate, nation, statusq,InstNo,  photo, combo, place, mimi; 
    int status;



   private void btnNextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

        fname=txtFirtsName.getText();
        lname=txtLastName.getText();
        mname=txtMiddleName.getText();
        InstNo=txtInstituteNo.getText();
        place=txtPlacBirth.getText();

        //photo=txtPicturePath.getText();
        status=combostatus.getSelectedIndex();

        Object dave=((JTextField)chooserBirthDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
        Object isa=combonation.getSelectedItem();

        Object photo=pictureName.getClass();
       // pst.setBytes();
        // bdate=((JTextField)chooserBirthDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();


        if(status==1){
            statusq=("In Active");
    }
        else{
            statusq="Active";}

        try{


       String addrecords="insert into brothers(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, BirthDate, BirthPlace, Nationality, InstituteNumber, Status, Picture) values('"+
        fname +"', '" +
        mname +"', '" +
        lname +"', '" +
        dave +"', '" +
        place +"', '" +
        isa +"', '" +
        InstNo +"', '" +
        statusq +"', '" +
        photo +"')"; 

        //wrapField();

        st.executeUpdate(addrecords);
        }
```

My file chooser Code and converting picture to binary:

```
 private void btnFileChooserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        JFileChooser izoChooser=new JFileChooser();
        izoChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File pictureBrother=izoChooser.getSelectedFile();
        pictureName=pictureBrother.getAbsolutePath();
        txtPicturePath.setText(pictureName);

        try {

          File image=new File(pictureName);
          FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(image);

          ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          byte[] buf=new byte[1024];

          for(int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1;){

              bos.write(buf,0,readNum);

          }
           person_image=bos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have declared these variable at the bottom of the code:

```
 private javax.swing.JTextField txtTrial;
    // End of variables declaration                   
String pictureName=null;
int s=0;
byte[] person_image=null; 
}
```

QUESTION: MY CODE THROWS NO ERROR BUT ON THE DATABASE, IT REGISTERS ONLY 8B ON THE BLOB COLUMN OF THE Picture, NO MATTER WHICH PICTURE I CHOOSE. BUT IF UPLOAD THE PICTURE FROM THE DATABASE DIRECTLY BY GOING TO DATABASE THEN UPLOADING, THE PICTURE GETS UPLOADED TO THE DATABASE. WHAT COULD BE THE ISSUE?

MY MAIN PROBLEM IS HERE: I GUESS, Object photo=pictureName.getClass();

WHAT SHOULD IT BE BECAUSE IF I WERE TO USE PREPARED STATEMENT THEN IT WOULD BE:
preparedStatemnt.setBytes(10, person_image);.

But there is no .getBytes();

Answer (score 0):

```
Object photo=pictureName.getClass();
```

That will only give you the class object of the `pictureName` variable. I doubt that is what you want. If you want to insert a BLOB with JDBC, you have to process the underlying byte stream. I suggest you take a read at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Oh, and please, use `PreparedStatement`s.

Comment: prepared statement failed with no apparent reason my friend, see below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196670/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-2-number-of-parameters-w...so can you pliz give me a clear pointer on this(just use my style, prepared statement has made my project drag without solution), kinda a newbiew on java

Comment: I see lots of reasons why that prepared statements did not work, but that's unrelated to this question.

Comment: Please show me here is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196670/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-2-number-of-parameters-w

Comment: Your other question has many good answers already. You should continue that discussion there. This question is about Blobs, and I have given you some pointers on that particular problem.